# Change Cursor Image While Hovering Over An Object Drawn At OpenGL And Displaying Object's Variables

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am currently working on a project that I use C++, OpenGL, Qt 5.9.2 and Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 on a 64 bit Operating System, Windows 10 Pro.

I have a user interface that I have created and in that user interface, there is a QGLWidget, that I am using for draw processes, with other widgets like push buttons and a dockWidget. I have a class Ball and it has variables(distance(double) and angle(int)) that determines where an instance of that Ball is going to be drawn inside the QGLWidget. Ball class has got 2 more variables that is, id(int), model(String) and year(int) Every other draw process draws lines except Ball drawings.

**Drawings are 2 dimensional.**

**Every Ball has the same color(rgb)!**

**First problem:** I want to left click to one of the Ball instances and I want to display it's id, model and year at The dockWidget.

**Second Problem:** While doing the stuff that I have mentioned at the First Problem section. I want the cursor image to change while hovering above any of the Ball instances, and change back to default Windows mouse cursor while not.

I have created a function that checks if the MouseEvent is LeftClick:

```
void DisplayManager::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* ev) { 

    if (ev->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) { // Balls Are Green
        if(// CHECK IF THERE IS A BALL AT THE CLICKED COORDINATES) {
            // DISPLAY THE X and Y OF THE BALL AT THE DOCK WIDGET
        }
    }
}
```

This is my initializeGL function: (**DisplayManager is the name of my QGLWidget**)

```
void DisplayManager::initializeGL() {
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL); // Enables the changing of the draw color with glColor() functions
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1); //sets a black background 1 0 0 1
}
```

On the basis this is a Picking problem and there are several information about it at the internet but I am not using GLUT and I am not using any shader. So in the light of all these I was unable to find any effective solution or clue about how can I accomplish all that I want.

I would be really glad if someone could help me with at least one of these problems.

Comment: There are two main solutions: 1. Read back contents of a GPU frame buffer and identify object under mouse by color (or something else which was rendered). ([Picking with an OpenGL hack](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/miscellaneous/clicking-on-objects/picking-with-an-opengl-hack/)) 2. Perform an intersection test on CPU side. For balls, this can be fairly simple: check whether mouse coordinate is inside the circle shape of the ball. Whether shaders are used or old fix-function-pipe functions is of minor relevance (except you expect something to copy/paste).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have currently finished working with the project. I thought that I should provide an answer to my question in case someone with a similar problem comes across with my question in the future.

```
void DisplayManager::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* ev) {

    // The processes that are being executed after a left mouse button click on the DisplayManager.
    if (ev->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        double aspectRatio = openGLWidgetWidth / openGLWidgetHeight;
        int xOfClicked = ev->x() - (openGLWidgetWidth / 2);
        int yOfClicked = - (ev->y() - (openGLWidgetHeight / 2));

        // The variable to be used for calculating fault tolerance of the click event.
        int distanceBetweenPressAndDraw = 0;

        // Executes the processes inside for every ball in vector.
        for (int i = 0; i < ballVector.length(); i++) {

            // Calculates the screen coordinates of the i'th ball.
            int rangeOfBallInScreenDistance = rangeToScreenDistance(ballVector.at(i).range);
            double screenXOfBall = rangeOfBallInScreenDistance * sin(ballVector.at(i).degree * DEGTORAD);
            double screenYOfBall = rangeOfBallInScreenDistance * cos(ballVector.at(i).degree * DEGTORAD);

            // Calculates the distance between pressed position and the i'th ball according to the screen coordinates.
            distanceBetweenPressAndDraw = sqrt(pow((screenXOfBall - xOfClicked), 2) + pow((screenYOfBall - yOfClicked), 2));

            // Decides if the clicked position is a ball (considering the fault tolerance).
            if (distanceBetweenPressAndDraw < 10) {
                emit printXY(QPointF(xOfClicked, yOfClicked)); // Prints the screen coordinates of the clicked positions (At the Dock Widget inside Main Window).
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This was the solution for my **First Problem**. I would be glad though if someone could answer my Second problem in a comment or answer somehow.